# UIActivityViewController freeze in first time

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

When I call the first time UIActivityViewController, the interaction is locked. After the first click it will be normal without locking interaction, does anyone know how to not catch the first time?

Comment: I am having a similar problem, even though the UIActivityViewController shows on the first time, it is really slow. After the first time it shows fast.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this can help. I had a similar issue, UIActivityViewController was pretty slow to appear the first time.

I solved it removing AirDrop from the supported activity types (through `excludedActivityTypes`) and it became super fast.
So if you are not interested in AirDrop (my case) you can do something like this:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
}
```

Note that `UIActivityTypeAirDrop` is only available starting from iOS 7.0.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really understand the problem - you alloc/init a UIActivityViewController and then you present it with `presentViewController:animated:completion`, correct? Make sure to call the `presentViewController..`. on the main thread. Sometimes UI stuff called on the wrong thread takes seconds to get executed. But it might also just be iOS - `UIActivityViewController` takes some time to check for available services and stuff, that might be the thing that's slowing it down too.